# Conditional permutation of combining multiple lists

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

Let's say I have two lists:

```
l1={1,2}
l2={a,b}
```

I want to find legal permutations of combining these two list in a way that the ordering of the members of each list, is preserved. In other words I am looking for a function ConditionalPermutation such that:

```
ConditionalPermutation[{1,2},{a,b}]=
{{1,2,a,b},{1,a,2,b},{a,b,1,2},{a,1,b,2},{1,a,b,2},{a,1,2,b}}
```

as you can see, in this simple case, we have 4 elements altogether, so the total number of permutations are 4*3*2=12. Out of these half have 2 appearing before 1 and also half have b appearing before a. Therefore the list of interest has (24/2)/2=6 legal permutations. In general there could be multiple l_i lists and each would have a different size.

I can code it with an imperative implementation, but I am looking for a neater way of doing it in Mathematica.

Ideally I want the solution to accept a general condition, or potentially one for each input list.

Comment: Just curious...what is "an imperative implementation" ?

Comment: as in like C++ code. not taking advantage of any of the higher order list manipulation functions in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not a C++ programmer and hadn't come across that term before.

Comment: Imperative is not a C++ term. it's basically the traditional form of writing programs. like writing for loops etc. One high level approach would be to create the full list and then filter it according to some conditions, but although that might look pretty, it's probably not very efficient.

Comment: I thought that type of coding was called *procedural*.

Comment: @march The two can be used interchangeably in this context. Procedural programming is just a more structured version of imperative programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have a list of lists. The function `listNumbersToElements` here takes such a list, along with a set of indices into it. For each index, it takes the next element from the correct list.

```
ClearAll[listNumbersToElements];
listNumbersToElements[inds_List, allLists_List] := Block[{c},
  c[_] = 0;
  Function[{listIndex},
    ++c[listIndex]; allLists[[listIndex, c[listIndex]]]] /@ inds]
```

Example:

```
In[157]:= listNumbersToElements[{1, 2, 1, 2}, {{1, 2}, {a, b}}]
listNumbersToElements[{1, 1, 2}, {{1, 2}, {a, b}}]
listNumbersToElements[{2, 2, 1, 1}, {{1, 2}, {a, b}}]


Out[157]= {1, a, 2, b}

Out[158]= {1, 2, a}

Out[159]= {a, b, 1, 2}
```

This function takes the list of lists, fills a list with `n` copies of each list's index, where `n` is the length of the respective list, then creates all permutations of the list of indices. Then it applies `listNumbersToElements` to each permutation, getting the final result as desired.

```
ClearAll[conditionalPermutation];
conditionalPermutation[lists__List] := 
 Module[{argsAsList = List@lists},
  listNumbersToElements[#, argsAsList] & /@ Permutations[Flatten[
     MapIndexed[Table[First[#2], Length[#1]] &, argsAsList],
     1]]]
```

Examples:

```
In[161]:= conditionalPermutation[{1, 2}, {a, b}]
conditionalPermutation[{1, 2}, {a, b, c}]

Out[161]= {{1, 2, a, b}, {1, a, 2, b}, {1, a, b, 2}, {a, 1, 2, b}, {a,
   1, b, 2}, {a, b, 1, 2}}

Out[162]= {{1, 2, a, b, c}, {1, a, 2, b, c}, {1, a, b, 2, c}, {1, a, 
  b, c, 2}, {a, 1, 2, b, c}, {a, 1, b, 2, c}, {a, 1, b, c, 2}, {a, b, 
  1, 2, c}, {a, b, 1, c, 2}, {a, b, c, 1, 2}}
```

Comment: I get an empty list as the result.  It does not appear that `l` (lowercase L) is defined in `Length[l]`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jim thanks for catching that. should be fixed now. accidentally copied an old cell  from the notebook.

Comment: +1 Very nice and elegant.  And works for multiple lists!

Comment: @MichaelCurry beautiful! Out of curiosity, How would you modify conditionalPermutation if you wanted it to accept a general condition, say have the elements in the opposite order, or have the elements from the lists separated by elements from another list, so that say only {1,a,2,b} and {a,1,b,2} would be legal.

Comment: hmmm. changes to the ordering would involve changes to `listNumbersToElements`: basically have it pick out the elements in some other order rather than just first to last. or just reverse the input list. generating all sets satisfying a partial ordering would require more substantial changes

Comment: as for your second condition, either replace the call to `Permutations` with something that generates only sets where two list elements don't occur repeatedly, or maybe use `Split` to check for lists that contain repeated adjacent elements and remove those lists.

Comment: @MichaelCurry Thanks. yeah I can see how we should modify the code to do each of those things. I meant to ask more from a design point of view. As in, would you pass the specialised listNumbersToElement as an argument to the outer function, or if you would pass a more readable expression identifying the condition (like a comparison function that you would pass to a sorting algorithm) and pass that to listNumbersToElements, etc. Basically I am trying to ask how much you think this problem can be generalised, if that makes any sense. Or, how similar these new problems are to the original one.

Comment: yeah I think functions passed in replacing both `listNumbersToElements` and the whole expression with `Permutations` makes sense. Maybe as Options with those two as defaults. but that's just my gut feeling. i don't know what the "idiomatic" right way would be, but I do think "generating list configurations" and "filling in configurations by picking list elements" are the two key operations here and could be generalized pretty far.

Answer (score 5):

This is an extended comment in that it gives (I hope) the number of arrangements rather than the arrangements.  However, I think the steps here will suggest a way to obtain the arrangements:

```
a = {a1, a2};
b = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
na = Length[a];
nb = Length[b];
ip = IntegerPartitions[nb, Min[na + 1, nb]]
(* {{4},{3,1},{2,2},{2,1,1}} *)
Sum[Binomial[na + 1, Length[ip[[i]]]] Length[Permutations[ip[[i]]] ], {i, Length[ip]}]
(* 15 *)
```

The logic is that there will be `na+1` places to put the numbers from `b`:

```
  x  a1  x  a2  x
```

For this example there are 3 places (`na+1`) to put items from `b`.  So we look at all of the `Min[na+1,nb]` integer partitions of `b` and weight those by the number of associated permutations.